# How to display python string in different lines?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to display the product titles and prices that I scraped from a link, and number them. So far, here's my code. However, I want to get the count number and the product name on the same line, and the product price on a different line. How would I revise my code to that?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
count = 1
for i in items:
    productName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text
    productPrice = i.find('h5').text
    count = count + 1
    print(str(count) + '. ' + productName + 'Price: ' + productPrice)
```

Comment: How about writing two print statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Right now the problem is that the products start and end with a `'\n'` newline.

## Solution

To get rid of that, we can use the `strip()` method. Also, for the print statement, we need to change `... + 'Price' + ...` to `... + '\nPrice' + ...` now that the products don't end with a newline (`'\n'`).

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
count = 1
for i in items:
    productName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip() # CHANGE 1
    productPrice = i.find('h5').text
    count = count + 1
    print(str(count) + '. ' + productName + '\nPrice: ' + productPrice) # CHANGE 2
```

This looks like a fun web scraping project! I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
count = 1
for i in items:
    productName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').get_text(strip=True)
    productPrice = i.find('h5').get_text(strip=True)
    count = count + 1
    print(str(count) + '. ' + productName + '\nPrice: ' + productPrice)
```

Output:

```
2. Short Dress
Price: $24.99
3. Patterned Slacks
Price: $29.99
4. Short Chiffon Dress
Price: $49.99
5. Off-the-shoulder Dress
Price: $59.99
6. V-neck Top
Price: $24.99
7. Short Chiffon Dress
Price: $49.99
8. V-neck Top
Price: $24.99
9. V-neck Top
Price: $24.99
10. Short Lace Dress
Price: $59.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of something you can do, just as an inspiration :)

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')

#A message that uses the array to number the items
print('the scraper found', len(items), 'items on the page')

#An empty array to append to
obj = []

#A function to make it easier to calculate with numbers
def getPrice(text):
    if text[0] == '$':
        return {'$':float(text[1:])}

#Append all the json items to the list 
for i in range(len(items)):
    obj.append(
            {
                'productName' : items[i].find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip(),
                'productPrice' : getPrice(items[i].find('h5').text.strip()),
            }
    )

print(json.dumps(obj, indent=2))
```